# matlab: "Index of element to remove exceeds matrix dimensions." When I am not removing any elemens

Tags: matlab, indexing

I get the error

```
???  Index of element to remove exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> myfile at 111
    C(i)=s{i,3};
```

the code being:

```
C=zeros(num_of_tris,1);
for i=1:size(C,1)
    C(i)=s{i,3};
end
```

I'm not showing the code for creating `s`, but I assume it's beside the point as `s` only appears on the right hand side of the assignment...

why does it say `element to remove`? which element am I removing?

Comment: I wonder if the value of s{i,3} is relevant. What is it?

Comment: Hi Noam, that is truly a strange error. I'd take a look at what is inside s at that particular index.

Comment: the code works fine on my end as is, you really need to show more information. set a breakpoint before and in the for loop and find out the story with s and C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so here's what is happening. `s` is probably initialized to an empty cell (NOTE: need not be entirely empty -- see last paragraph). So, indexing an element of `s` as `s{i,3}` returns `[]`. The MATLAB operation to remove an element of a vector is

```
C(i)=[];
```

So when you loop through, you're removing the elements of `C` one by one, and eventually, the index `i` exceeds the size of the (now diminished) vector.

Here's a small example that reproduces your problem:

```
s=cell(10,5);           %#initialize s to an empty cell
%#note that any cell returns []
s{3,4}

ans =

     []

%#This is your code from above
C=zeros(10,1);          %#initialize C
for i=1:size(C,1)
    C(i)=s{i,3};
end
```

> ???  Index of element to remove exceeds matrix dimensions.

You'll find that the index `i` when you get this error is `numel(C)/2+1`. In other words, till `i=5` (in this example), you're removing every odd element of `C` and at `i=6`, the number of elements remaining in `C` is 5, and so you get an index out of bounds error.

---

#### NOTE:

`s` need not even be entirely empty. Consider this example:

```
s=cell(10,1);
s([1,2,6,8])=num2cell(rand(4,1));
C=zeros(10,1);
for i=1:numel(C)
    C(i)=s{i};
end
```

> ???  Index of element to remove exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: That's what I thought, but according to OP's comment, s{i, 3} is holding the value of 6 at the time of the exception.

Comment: @Amac: I just saw that comment, and I _think_ OP might be mistaken about it. If it were so, the OP shouldn't have gotten an error, because MATLAB just grows the array in case of an assignment. The closest error message in this case is "Index exceeds matrix dimensions". The "...element to remove..." part clearly shows some removal via assignment to empty matrix is going on.

Comment: This is a bug. The only way you are supposed to be able to perform parenthesis deletion is by assigning the literal "[]". For example, `x=[]; y(i)=x;` won't perform paren deletion, but `y(i)=[];` will. I've logged the bug (I work for The MathWorks).

Comment: @SCFrench: Thanks for your comment and bringing up the issue at The Mathworks.